# sum up text values in JSON Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json

i am in a bit tricky situation. I fetch some price values from a sqlite db and store it in a react state.

the response looks like: `[{"price":50},{"price":"49,95"}]`

i need to store these values as TEXT insted of INTEGER, because i have a lot of differrent decimal places. also using float in sqlite will not give me exact values, see the problem in this example: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15729/storing-prices-in-sqlite-what-data-type-to-use

So to my main problem: how can i extract and convert the values from the json array to numbers, and sum it up?

Comment: What does _"i have a lot of differrent decimal places"_ mean? There are different approaches to avoid rounding errors. Convert the strings and numbers to integers: `50` -> `5000`, `"49,95"` -> `4995`. Use a library for fixed-point arithmetic. Use a library for infinite precision. Do the calculation based on strings.

Comment: Wouldn't the preferred option be to make sure the data you're receiving from the database is sanitised and correct, and that all the values were text, and not a mix of numbers/text?

Comment: @jabaa this means, some values are 49.95, some are 65.7862437482

Comment: In that case, the first approach won't work. But the other 3 still work. I guess, under the hood, all 3 approaches do something similar. They store each digit as a separate element in a container (string, array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use a library, you could convert all numbers to strings and write your own sum function for strings. This algorithm supports arbitrary long strings containing numbers and returns exact results without rounding errors.

```js
function add(l, r, sep) {
  if (!sep) sep = '.';
  const [ll, lr] = l.split(/[,.]/).map(el => el.split('').map(Number));
  const [rl, rr] = r.split(/[,.]/).map(el => el.split('').map(Number));
  let carry = 0;
  const result = [[], []];
  for (let i = Math.max(lr?.length ?? 0, rr?.length ?? 0); i > 0; --i) {
    result[1][i - 1] = (lr?.[i - 1] ?? 0) + (rr?.[i - 1] ?? 0) + carry;
    carry = Math.floor(result[1][i - 1] / 10);
    result[1][i - 1] %= 10;
  }
  
  for (let il = ll.length, ir = rl.length, iResult = Math.max(ll.length, rl.length); iResult > 0; --il, --ir, --iResult) {
    result[0][iResult - 1] = (ll[il - 1] ?? 0) + (rl[ir - 1] ?? 0) + carry;
    carry = Math.floor(result[0][iResult - 1] / 10);
    result[0][iResult - 1] %= 10;
  }
  if (carry) result[0] = [carry, ...result[0]];
  return result[0].join('') + sep + result[1].join('');
}

function sum(arr, sep) {
  return arr.map(el => String(el.price)).reduce((acc, el) => add(acc, el, sep));
}

console.log(sum([{ "price": "0.9" }, { "price": "1.2" }], ','));
console.log(sum([{ "price": "100000000" }, { "price": "0.0000002" }]));
console.log(sum([{ "price": 123.123 }, { "price": "1234.5678" }, { "price": "9876,54321" }, { "price": "111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111.111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111"}]));
```

Comment: Thanks! this is exactly what im looking for!